# addThis button not clickable via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, addthis, add-this-event

I've tried looking at the documentation for addThis and it seems like it's being updated or something because all the links these help posts link to don't even mention the API bits they describe.

Anyway,

I just need to be able to programmatically click an addThis button. However, I can't seem to do it via console before I implement it in my code.

I read that this has something to do with how the addThis listeners are added only when the document is done loading. This doesn't make sense to me because even if I manually try to trigger a click in console, it still does nothing but return the html of the link I'm trying to trigger. For example:

```
   `$('.at-svc-facebook').click();`

OR `$('.at-svc-facebook').trigger('click');`

OR `$('.at-share-btn.at-svc-facebook').click();`
```

I mean, by the time I open console the dom is ready. So then what else might be preventing me from clicking these buttons via jQuery?

I've tried adding a listener to an element myself, and then clicking it programmatically, and it works. So something is different about the way addThis listens for a click. I may update this question with something I find after inspecting their js.

===================

This is what is in the DOM which addThis populates and listens to:

```
 <div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox"></div>
```

This is what ^ that code is turned in to from addThis:

```
<div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox" data-url="http://localhost:8001/halloween/" data-title="33 Halloween Costume Ideas">
  <div id="atstbx" class="at-share-tbx-element addthis_32x32_style addthis-smartlayers addthis-animated at4-show">
      <a class="at-share-btn at-svc-facebook">
          <span class="at4-icon aticon-facebook" title="Facebook"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="at-share-btn at-svc-twitter">
          <span class="at4-icon aticon-twitter" title="Twitter"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="at-share-btn at-svc-google_plusone_share">
          <span class="at4-icon aticon-google_plusone_share" title="Google+"></span>
      </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, you can see the jQuery I'm using to click the buttons and the code it's trying to click.

Comment: show us the code you are working on, and also the function you want to perform on click.

Comment: Try `var class_name=$(this).attr('class')`

Comment: They don't seem to have the class `"social-bar"`

Comment: "social-bar" is wrapped around the ul

Comment: @GuruprasadRao It will give the same result, I'm not sure how that would help.

Comment: can you show the click function? what is happening there , may be click is being triggered and  problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @OAD Sure, that's in the bullet points.

Comment: Alright then can you create a minimal fiddle replicating the problem?

Comment: @ninja08 Your HTML structure is important in this question, generally removing your code is a bad thing as you cannot be certain that your code will always be correct, and it's possible it can be a problem with your code. For example I didn't see a `at-svc-facebook` class in the HTML you provided, can you be sure that selector is correct?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Yeah I understand that. So what I've done is add the addThis html to the question, since that's what needs focus. You can see from the question now the HTML that I'm trying to trigger, and the jQuery I'm using to click stuff.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek All that matters right now is that a 'click' event can't be triggered on that code, even though addThis is listening for a click event on those links.

Comment: Why would someone want to close this quesiton. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that addThis was putting a second link with the exact same class in the DOM for some reason. It generates some HTML and appends it to body.

So what I needed to do to select the button and trigger a click was to specify the 2nd element in the array of elements and call click on that one. Like so:

```
$('.at-svc-facebook')[1].click();
```

Now, the next problem I face is chrome block a programatic popup, but that's beyond the scope of this question. :(

Comment: you can add another Q regarding new issue, if you have found solution of your problem you can mark your ans as accepted so that someone facing same problem can be helped out.

Comment: Thanks OAD. I tried to accept my answer but it said I need to wait 2 days. :/

Comment: I would just like to add, the reason this code works is because you're not calling click on the jQuery selector anymore, you're calling `.click()` on the javascript DOM element. When you limit the jQuery selector to an element in the array (like `[1]`) that returns the plain javascript object. `click()` is a method of the javascript DOM object, not jQuery. For some reason trying to trigger the click using jQuery fails.

Answer (score 0):

change the

```
var class_name = $(this)[0].className;
```

as below,

```
var class_name = $(this)[0].attr('class');
```

and it'll work. :)

Comment: I've already explained why this isn't correct in @OAD answer, that isn't the problem and the OP isn't doing anything wrong with access the classname.